# MS-SQL: How to select records with encoded UTC times?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Summary:** How to extract records that belong to the UTC time interval, when the UTC time in the key column is encoded?

**The UTC encoding:** I do have a third-party table where records contain UTC time encoded as strings like `'2456065.80700942:0000002F'`. To get the UTC of the `DATETIME` type, the following formula can be used:

```
CAST((CAST(LEFT(encodedUTC, 16) AS FLOAT) - 2415020.5) AS DATETIME)
```

They say, the part before the colon is the Julian date encoded to float (and the float to the string). I did not check, it seems to work.

**The query:** Now I have `@fromUTC` and `@toUTC` of the `DATETIME` type. I can select:

```
SELECT CAST((CAST(LEFT(d.UTC, 16) AS FLOAT) - 2415020.5) AS DATETIME) AS UTC,
       ...
FROM dbo.Data AS d
WHERE CAST((CAST(LEFT(d.UTC, 16) AS FLOAT) - 2415020.5) AS DATETIME) > @fromUTC 
      AND CAST((CAST(LEFT(d.UTC, 16) AS FLOAT) - 2415020.5) AS DATETIME) < @toUTC
```

(I am not using `BETWEEN` as I do not want to get the records with equal times.) It works, but the problem is that the conversion formula is repeated 3 times (and I do not like the repeating of the same code if it is not neccessary).

My question is: How can I write the `SELECT` better?

Thanks for your time and information,

Petr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider either adding a view that includes this calculation, or a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on the table itself (if you can change the table definition).

Either of these approaches would lead to a cleaner final select. There's likely some performance considerations based on how often you select versus insert, so will probably shade you one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

use CTE like

```
;with  cteName (UTC) as 
(
select SELECT CAST((CAST(LEFT(d.UTC, 16) AS FLOAT) - 2415020.5) AS DATETIME) AS UTC
FROM dbo.Data
)
select UTC
from cts where uct > @fromUTC and utc < @toUTC
```